# error: binding ‘const double’ to reference of type ‘double&’ discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, ranged-loops

I receive error

> binding ‘const double’ to reference of type ‘double&’ discards qualifiers

when compiling:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘Point square(const Point&)’:
main.cpp:14:28: error: binding ‘const double’ to reference of type ‘double&’ discards qualifiers
  for(double &a:{Q.x,Q.y,Q.z})
                            ^
```

While there are other questions online about this error, I am looking for a solution  this particular code. I insist on using ranged for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Point
{
public:
    double x,y,z;
};

Point square(const Point &P)
{
    Point Q=P;
    for(double &a:{Q.x,Q.y,Q.z})
        a*=a;
    return Q;
}

int main()
{
    Point P{0.1,1.0,10.0};
    Point Q=square(P);
    std::cout<<"----------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Q.x: "<<Q.x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Q.y: "<<Q.y<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Q.z: "<<Q.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"----------------"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why pass P? Why not `P.square()`?

Comment: @stark, this is a MWE, in practice the function is far more customized. It is not worth putting the function in the class. BTW, a method will have a similar problem, doesn't it?

Comment: `I insist on using ranged for. ` .. why?

Comment: @txtechhelp, otherwise I should write the code multiple times.

Comment: Write what code multiple times? You're modifying a temporary variable that doesn't modify anything. Is your intent to multiple the 3 variables, e.g. `double t = x * y * z;`? It's not clear from your code what you're trying to actually do, and _why_ you **must** use a ranged for loop.

Comment: @txtechhelp, this is a MWE. In practice I will use a curve function. The curve is highly customizable and it is not a part of nature of `Point`. Semantically, this is not acceptable to embed it in the class. And also NO one else can extend the code in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An initializer list created by `{Q.x,Q.y,Q.z}` in context of your `for` is still based on a separate array of values. Even if you somehow managed to modify these values, it still wouldn't affect your `Q`, which is apparently your intent. But you can't modify them anyway, since that array consists of `const` elements (which is what the compiler is telling you).

If you want a ranged `for` you can use an old C-era trick

```
for (double *a : { &Q.x, &Q.y, &Q.z })
  *a *= *a;
```

or, alternatively

```
for (auto a : { std::ref(Q.x), std::ref(Q.y), std::ref(Q.z) })
  a *= a;
```

Comment: Does the latter code using `std::ref` have any extra overhead?

Comment: @ar2015:Theoretically, it might. But there's no credible reason to, in any self-respecting implementation.

Comment: is it correct if I use `double &` instead of `auto`?

Comment: @ar2015: Yes, certainly. `std::reference_wrapper`  does have conversion operator to the stored reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the correct answer is:

`for_each(std::tie(x, y, z), [](auto& a){a *= a;});`

Defined as follow:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t ...Indices>
void for_each_impl(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{1,
        (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...
    };
}
template <typename Tuple, typename F>
void for_each(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f) {
    constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value;
    for_each_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f),
                  std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main(){
    double x, y, z;
    for_each(std::tie(x, y, z), [](auto& a){a *= a;});
}
```

Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/67394/82510

Comment: @ar2015, the point of my answer is to say that if the x, y, z are the same type, then it is better to use `std::array<double, 3>` to represent or wrap the Point, which is already a container that you can iterate over (use `for` range). Computational geometry usually defines the quantities `enum {X, Y, Z}` to access `p[X], p[Y], p[Z]` if this is the notation you want to use (http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html) . If, on the other hand, x, y, z are different types (not your case) then this answer is basically the only solution.